# Getting "Cannot access file exception

Tags: c#

I am getting following exception.
"COMException was unhandled"
"Can not access file_name.xls"

```
string currentDir=Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

if (defaultButtonClicked)
{

_csvFilePath = Path.Combine(currentDir, "File Name_" + DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") + ".xls");
                    defaultButtonClicked = false;

}

else if (dateSpecificSearchButtonClicked)

               {
                    var dateTemp = calChoosedate.Value.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
                    _csvFilePath = Path.Combine(currentDir, "File Name_" + dateTemp + ".xls");
                    dateSpecificSearchButtonClicked = false;
                }


workBook.SaveAs(_csvFilePath, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true, false, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

                workBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(application)
```

Comment: There is a good chance you do not have write permission to whatever GetCurrentDirectory() returned.

Comment: Are you sure that one of the two IF blocks are taken? Otherwise what will be the value of __csvFilePath_?

Comment: based on your code, I can find a reason that the thrown error has this file name "file_name.xls"

Comment: @Steve: Good point.  I would add `else throw new Exception("File name could not be set");` or similar.  Always code defensively.

Comment: Previously, I was working with .csv file and code was working fine. Also, every time one of two IF blocks have been taken in code, but when I changed code from .csv to .xls, this is giving exception. I also tried with hard coded file path, it is working.

Comment: Sounds like you might be trying to save a worksheet with the name of one you currently have open.